# Hibernate, Oracle, Sequence and One To Many Problem

Tags: oracle, hibernate, save, one-to-many

I am having an issue with doing a one line save on a one to many object.  That foreign key does not get populated in the child objects.  Aren't they suppose to automatically from Hibernate?  The BadgeID never gets inserted into the BadgeLevel.BadgeID.

Badge.java

```
@Basic
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="BADGE_SEQUENCE")
@SequenceGenerator(name="BADGE_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "BADGE_SEQUENCE")
@Column(name = "ID", nullable=false, unique=true)
    public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy="badge", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(value=FetchMode.SELECT)
public List<BadgeLevel> getBadgeLevels() {
   return this.badgelevels;
}
```

BadgeLevel.java

```
@Basic
@Id
@NotNull
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="BADGELEVEL_SEQUENCE")
@SequenceGenerator(name="BADGELEVEL_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "BADGELEVEL_SEQUENCE")
@Column(name = "ID", nullable=false, unique=true)
    public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "BADGEID")
public Badge getBadge() {
    return this.badge;
}

/**
 * set badge
 */
public void setBadge(Badge badge) {
    this.badge = badge;
}
```

Comment: How are you linking the two objects? Please, show us the code which is between session.open and session.close.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling save on Badge, try the following

```
......

for(BadgeLevel badgeLevel : badge.getBadegeLevels()
{
   badgeLevel.setBadge(badge);
}
repo.save(badge);
```

Comment: I did and it worked, but then that BadgeLevel also had a new object called Asset attached to it, that needed to be saved also before BadgeLevel could.  I just went the route of doing them one by one.  I miss LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: Yea in Hibernate, we have to take care while persisting bi-directional relationships and it can be a pain sometimes.